# How to get xgterm

Tags: software-installation

I have installed scisoft version 7.5. 
I need to run iraf in the scisoft from xgterm. But when I type xgterm in bash terminal it shows following message,

```
No command 'xgterm' found, did you mean:
Command 'xterm' from package 'xterm' (main)
xgterm: command not found
```

I guess xgterm is not on my system and I can't find it in ubuntu repository. How to get xgterm for Ubuntu 12.04?

Comment: Where/How you installed xgterm?

Answer (score 1):

I installed current IRAF (v216.1) under Ubuntu 12.04 and run in a similar error. Turned out that xgterm is on the system, but just not in the path. In my case I had to create this symbolic link:

```
$ ln -s ~/opt/iraf.v2161/vendor/x11iraf/bin.linux/xgterm .iraf/bin/
```

(where ~/opt/iraf.v2161/ is the root directory in which I installed iraf).

Now xgterm it is available and iraf command launches correctly

```
$ which xgterm
~/.iraf/bin/xgterm
```

I assume that under Scisoft the xgterm binary is in the same place e.g.

```
[scisoft-root-dir]/x11iraf/bin.linux/
```

alternatively you can get a statically linked executable this way

```
$ wget ftp://iraf.noao.edu/pub/fitz/xgterm.STATIC
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is old, but I found a very useful solution on the [official IRAF website](http://iraf.net/forum/viewtopic.php?showtopic=1468252). One needs to download statically linked binaries from

```
ftp://iraf.noao.edu/pub/fitz/xgterm.STATIC
ftp://iraf.noao.edu/pub/fitz/ximtool.STATIC
```

make them executable:

```
chmod 755 /path/xgterm.STATIC
```

And then manually move them in the `/usr/local/bin`

```
sudo mv /path//xgterm.STATIC /usr/local/bin/xgterm
```

(And similarly for ximtool)

Comment: It seems that the `xgterm` and `ximtool` static binaries were moved or removed from that FTP server.  I'm not entirely sure if they're distributing the static builds any more.